# Check if server received data after timeout

Tags: c++, asp.net-web-api, libcurl

I made a program that uses serveral RestAPI's of Bitcoin exchanges, e.g. [Bitstamp](https://www.bitstamp.net/market/tradeview/)

There is a function that allows me to do a trade: sell or buy Bitcoin for a specific price. Simplified, you have to call a URL with parameters like this:

```
https://www.bitstamp.net/api/trade?price=100&amount=1&type=sell
```

The server then answers in JSON. Example:

```
{"error":"","message":"Sold 1 BTC @ 100$"}
```

If the trade was successful, my program continues. If it was not, it tries again (depending on the error message).

However, there is one problem. I'm using libcurl for the communication with the server and I set the CURLOPT_TIMEOUT to two seconds. It almost always works, but sometimes I get the following error:

```
Code #28: Operation timed out after 2000 milliseconds with 0 bytes received
```

When this happens, my program tries to trade again. But sometimes, despite the timeout, the trade was already made, which means it is done multiple times because my code tries again.

Can I somehow find out if the server atleast received all the data? The thing is if I increase CURLOPT_TIMEOUT to say 10 seconds, and the server does not answer, I have the same problem. So this is not a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not know details of Bitstamp, but here is how HTTP works. Client sends a request to a server and receives a response. In the response, details about success or failure are described (by using HTTP error codes). However, if a timeout is received, then client has no information about it's request:

- is it sent to the server;
- did server receive it;
- if server received the request, did it manage to process;
- maybe server processed the request, but sending back the response failed due to the network issues.

For that reason, one should not count that the request was successful, and should resend the request. The problem you have described is certainly possible - server received the request, processed it but did not manage to send back the response. For that reason, other more complex protocols should be used, unfortunately HTTP is not one of them because of it's request-response nature.

Perhaps you should check if the given REST API gives some status for the transactions.

Answer (score 1):

You **are** supposed to wait for the HTTP response to be a little bit more sure wether your request was successfully processed or not.

If you can access to the file descriptor, you can call `ioctl()` with the `SIOCOUTQ` (Linux) or `FIONWRITE` (BSD) -- I don't know the equivalent for Windows --, to check for unacknowledged sent data at socket level, before totally aborting you connection.

The problem is that it wouldn't be totally error-free either.  Even though TCP is stateful at transport level, HTTP is stateless at application level.  If your application needs transactional behavior (you dealing with currency, after all, aren't you?), it should provide a means for that.

All that said, I think two seconds might be too little.  If you need speed because of multiple operations or something like that, consider parallelizing your connections.